# Google Maps API latitude/longitude pair to Google Fusion Tables query

Tags: javascript, jquery, geospatial, google-maps

I'm trying to learn JavaScript, and as a practice tool I recently wrote a [simple web app](http://sco-tt.github.io/What-s-My-Climate-Zone/) that uses the Google Maps API Geocoder to get the latitude and longitude of a location (user input), manipulate them, then query those against a Google Fusion Table listing the world's climate zone codes according to the [Köppen-Geiger climate classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification). Basically people can type in a location and find out what climate zone it is, and see a map with the zones overlaid if they want it (might be of interest to geography buffs).

All of the logic is in a JavaScript file copied below. It was my goal to write as much of it without jQuery as possible, so I only use jQuery to handle the Fusion Tables request and to add/remove classes.

I've run it through JShint, and fixed most of the things mentioned there. I had the hardest time handling the list of alternative locations that Google returns, and did it with some funky global variables, a function within a `for` loop, and some other certainly coding practices. Those are `changeMapLocation()` and `buildAltLocationList()`.

Everything works like I want it to, but this is a learning project I'd appreciate any suggestions for refactoring, design factors, maintainability, etc.

```
/* Google Address to coordinates code from:
http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/GoogleMaps-JS-API-address-to-coordinates-transformation-text-to-LatLng
*/
(function () { // Begin scoping function
    "use strict";
    var map = null;
    var returnedLocation;
    var altLocationsList;
    var isAlt = false;
    var markersArray = [];


    /*Initializing the map and input elements*/

    window.onload = function () {
        // initialize the map and set options
        var mapHolder = document.getElementById("map-holder");
        map = new google.maps.Map(
            mapHolder,
            {
                zoom: 3,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                },
                panControl: true,
                panControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                },
                streetViewControl: false
            }
        );

        // centering the map
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(20.2, 0.1));

        // Add event listeners

        //Search field - button click

        document.getElementById("search").onclick = function () {
            var address = document.getElementById("searchtext").value;
            addressToLocation(address, changeMapLocation);
            isAlt = false;
            clearResultsLaunchSpinner();
        };

        //Search field - hit enter

         document.getElementById("searchtext").onkeydown = function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                var address = document.getElementById("searchtext").value;
                addressToLocation(address, changeMapLocation);
                isAlt = false;
                clearResultsLaunchSpinner();
            }
        };

        document.getElementById("layer-toggle").onclick = function () {
            toggleLayer(0);
        };
    };


    function clearResultsLaunchSpinner () {
        $(document.body).removeClass("showing-results");
        document.getElementById("locationName").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("zoneDescription").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("zoneOutput").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("numOfAlts").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("altIds").innerHTML="";
        clearOverlays();
        $(document.body).addClass("active");
    }

    function clearOverlays() {
        for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }
            markersArray = [];
    }

    /*Zooming to location and passing reults to climate zone query*/

    function changeMapLocation(locations) {
        clearResultsLaunchSpinner();

        // isAlt determine if this is inputed through the search field or clicked on in the list of alternates and called from buildAltLocationsList()

        if(locations && locations.length && isAlt === false) {


            //Set up a marker and pan map to our best location
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: locations[0].location
            });
            markersArray.push(marker);

            returnedLocation = locations[0].text + "<br>(" + parseFloat(locations[0].location.k).toFixed(2) + ", " + parseFloat(locations[0].location.B).toFixed(2) + ")";
            map.panTo(locations[0].location);
            map.setZoom(6);
            //send lat/lng pair to rounder
            rounder([locations[0].location.k, locations[0].location.B]);  

            //Redfine global var so it can be used at the end of Climate Zone query to to call buildAltLocationsList()
            altLocationsList = locations;

        } 

        else if (isAlt === true) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: locations.location
            });
            markersArray.push(marker);

            returnedLocation = locations.text + "<br>(" + parseFloat(locations.location.k).toFixed(2) + ", " + parseFloat(locations.location.B).toFixed(2) + ")";
            map.panTo(locations);
            map.setZoom(6);
            //send lat/lng pair to rounder
            rounder([locations.location.k, locations.location.B]); 

        }
        else {
            describeClimatezone (null);
        }

    }

    function buildAltLocationsList (locations) {
        //Determine whether or not to include the "best result" in altLocationsList or not

        var arrIndex;
        if (isAlt === false ) {
            arrIndex = 1;
        }
        else {
            arrIndex = 0;
        }

        document.getElementById("altIds").innerHTML = "";

        if (locations.length > 1) {
            document.getElementById("numOfAlts").innerHTML = locations.length-arrIndex + " alternate locations found. Click to search:";

            for(var i=arrIndex; i<locations.length; i++) {  
                document.getElementById("altIds").innerHTML += "<li id = alt" + i + "><a>" + locations[i].text + "</a></li>";
            }

            //Separate for loop to build the click handler for each li
            for(var z=arrIndex; z<locations.length; z++) {  
                (function (z) {
                    document.getElementById("alt" + z).onclick = function () {
                        if (window.console.firebug !== undefined) {
                            console.log(locations[z]);
                        }
                        else {
                            isAlt = true;
                            changeMapLocation(locations[z]);
                        }
                    };
                })(z);
            } //End 2nd for loop
        }           
    }


    // Prepping data for Fusion Table Query. 
    // Everything has to be rounded to nearest .25 or .75 to match the data

    function rounder (x) {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var xDecimal = (x[i] % 1);
            if (xDecimal >= 0 && xDecimal <= 0.5) {
                x[i] += (0.25 - xDecimal);
            }
             if (xDecimal > 0.5 && xDecimal < 1) {
                x[i] += (0.75 - xDecimal);
            }
            if (xDecimal >= -0.5 && xDecimal  < 0) {
                 x[i] += (-0.25 - xDecimal);
             }
            if (xDecimal > -1.00 && xDecimal < -0.5) {
                x[i] += (-0.75 - xDecimal);
           }
        }
       determineClimateZone(x[0], x[1]);
    }

    // Fusion Table Query of list of table of worldwide lat/lng pairs and their climate zone
    // https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1GQfBT-PXojUbIZP7_tkILYKNjHaQjYqop9gkosho

      function determineClimateZone(lat, lng) {
       var query =    "SELECT 'Cls' FROM " +
                       "1GQfBT-PXojUbIZP7_tkILYKNjHaQjYqop9gkosho" +
                       " WHERE 'Lat' = '" + lat + "' AND Lon = '" + lng + "'";
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);

        // Construct the URL
        var url = ["https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query"];
        url.push("?sql=" + encodedQuery);
        url.push("&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ");
        url.push("&callback=?");

        // Send the JSONP request using jQuery
        $.ajax({
          url: url.join(""),
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (data) {
            describeClimatezone(data.rows[0]);
          }
        });
      }

    function describeClimatezone (climateZone) {
        var czArray = [
            ["Af","Tropical rainforest"],
            ["Am","Tropical monsoon"],
            ["Aw","Tropical wet and dry or savanna"],
            ["As","Tropical wet and dry or savanna ('summer' dry season)"],
            ["BWh","Subtropical desert"],
            ["BSh","Subtropical steppe"],
            ["BWk","Mid-latitude desert"],
            ["BSk","Mid-latitude steppe"],         
            ["Csa","Mediterranean, hot summer"], 
            ["Csb","Mediterranean, warm summer"],             
            ["Cfa","Humid subtropical, no dry season"],
            ["Cwa","Humid subtropical, dry winter"],
            ["Cwb","Temperate highland tropical climate with dry winters"],
            ["Cwc","Temperate highland tropical climate with dry winters"],
            ["Cfb","Marine west coast, warm summer"],
            ["Cfc","Marine west coast, cool summer"],
            ["Dfa","Humid continental, no dry season, hot summer"],
            ["Dfb","Humid continental, no dry season, warm summer"],
            ["Dwa","Humid continental, severe dry winter, hot summer"],
            ["Dwb","Humid continental, severe dry winter, warm summer"],
            ["Dsb","Humid continental, dry warm summer"],                 
            ["Dfc","Subartic, severe winter, no dry season, cool summer"], 
            ["Dfd","Subartic, severe very cold winter, no dry season, cool summer"],             
            ["Dwc","Subartic, dry winter, cool summer"],
            ["Dsc","Subartic, subalpine"],
            ["Dwd","Subartic, very cold and dry winter, cool summer"],
            ["ET","Tundra"],
            ["EF","Ice Cap"]
    ];
        var zoneDescriptionText;

        for (var i = 0; i < czArray.length; i++) {
            if (climateZone == czArray[i][0]) {
                zoneDescriptionText = czArray[i][1];
            }
            else if (climateZone === null) {
                zoneDescriptionText = "Location Not Found! Look at an atlas!";
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("locationName").innerHTML = "Showing Results for: <br>" + returnedLocation;
        document.getElementById("zoneOutput").innerHTML = document.getElementById("zoneOutput").innerHTML + climateZone;
        document.getElementById("zoneDescription").innerHTML = document.getElementById("zoneDescription").innerHTML + zoneDescriptionText;  

        //Change classes in DOM to hide spinner
        $(document.body).removeClass("active");
        $(document.body).addClass("showing-results");

        //Now that the climate zone has been returned, call function to build a list of alternate locations returned by Google's Geocode
        buildAltLocationsList(altLocationsList);

    }

    // converting the address's string to a google.maps.LatLng object
    function addressToLocation(address, callback) {
        var isAlt = false;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode(
            {
                address: address
            }, 
            function(results, status) {
                var resultLocations = [];

                if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if(results) {
                        var numOfResults = results.length;
                        for(var i=0; i<numOfResults; i++) {
                            var result = results[i];
                            resultLocations.push(
                                {
                                    text:result.formatted_address,
                                    addressStr:result.formatted_address,
                                    location:result.geometry.location,
                                    lat:result.geometry.location.lat(),
                                    lng:result.geometry.location.lng(),
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                } else if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                    // address not found
                }

                if(resultLocations.length > 0) {
                    callback(resultLocations, false);
                } else {
                    callback(null);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    //define layer

    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("https://sco-tt.github.io/What-s-My-Climate-Zone/Koeppen-Geiger-GE.kmz",
    {preserveViewport: true});

    //toggle kmz layer function

    function toggleLayer() {
        if(layer.getMap()===null) {
            layer.setMap(map);
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            $("#layer-toggle").addClass("pure-button-active");
        }
        else {
            layer.setMap(null);
            $("#layer-toggle").removeClass("pure-button-active");

        }
    }    
})();         // End scoping function
```

Comment: It returns `Humid subtropical, no dry season` for New York City. That sounds wrong. The climate for Belgium seems correct.

Comment: It does sound wrong, as the mid-Atlantic US doesn't seem subtropical, but that's how the classification system is set up. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_New_York_City#Climate): 

_Although it is not in the subtropics and its winters are cold, New York has a humid subtropical climate according to the Köppen climate classification because the coldest months' average temperatures are not low enough for persistent snow cover, between 32.5 and 33.0 °F (0.3 and 0.6 °C) at all three reporting stations within the city._

Answer (score 3):

From a once over:

- I like `'use strict';`
- You have a few magic constants

  - `zoom: 3,` <- What does 3 mean ? Well named constants would help the reader
  - `new google.maps.LatLng(20.2, 0.1)` <- Curious..
- Consider `addEventListener` or jQueryevent handling instead of assigning listener directly like here:
  `document.getElementById("search").onclick` <- This does not play nice
- In my mind, if you use jQuery at all you should it for looking up elements.
  `document.getElementById("search")` <> `$("#search")`
- Double newlines to separate code might be over the top, I would stick to single newlines
- I would write the following with a ternary:

  ```
  var arrIndex;
  if (isAlt === false ) {
      arrIndex = 1;
  }
  else {
      arrIndex = 0;
  }
  ```

  could be

  ```
  var arrIndex = isAlt?0:1;
  ```
- Your `rounder` calls `determineClimateZone`, that should not be the job of `rounder`
- I would have called `rounder` `roundCoordinates`
- I would play around with having 1 function to set `locationName`, `zoneDescription` instead of 2, you are now mixing UI and model in `describeClimatezone`
- From a much higher level, if ever your lookup table changes from rounding to `.25` and `.75` (which is such a weird choice, so it seems likely to happen), then your code is broken. I would spend some time to analyze the fusion table and find the correct entry independent of rounding choices.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips! How do you recommend that I call `determineClimateZone`?